# A .htaccess redirect while editing the query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect to a new domain, while keeping the query string but in a modified way.

For example, I want to redirect:

```
http://guides.freshstoreinstant.com/fresh-store-instant/how-to-find-your-amazon-affiliate-key-secret-key
```

to

```
https://guides.freshlabs.group/search?query=how+to+find+your+amazon+affiliate+key+secret+key
```

So I am wanting to:

1. Take the last "folder" from the original URL (`how-to-find-your-amazon-affiliate-key-secret-key`)
2. Replace `-` with `+`
3. Append the result to `https://guides.freshlabs.group/search?query=` and redirect with 301

I tried a few things and know a little bit about `.htaccess` but this one has me stumped

**UPDATE**

This could be easier using a combination of `.htaccess` and PHP. Can I use `.htaccess` to rewrite all URLs to `index.php`, then use PHP to replace the characters and redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`. Try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(fresh-store-instant)/([^/]*)-([^/]*)$ $1/$2+$3 [N]
RewriteRule ^fresh-store-instant/([^/]+)$ https://guides.freshlabs.group/search?query=$1 [R=302,L]
```

1. The first rule repeatedly rewrites the request (internally) replacing all `-` (hyphens) with `+` in the second path segment. The `N` (`next`) flag explicitly triggers the rewriting loop. This should be used with caution; as with any recursive-like behaviour, it needs to *fail* at some point. (NB: A `+` in the URL-path is simply a literal `+`.)
2. Once all the hyphens have been replaced, the second rule triggers an external redirect to the other domain, copying the second path segment (now containing `+`) to the query string in the target URL. (NB: A `+` in the query string part of the URL is seen as an encoded *space* by the receiving server.)

Note that this is a temporary (302) redirect. Only change to a 301 (permanent) once you have confirmed it works OK - to avoid caching issues.

Clear your browser cache before testing.

> ...while keeping the query string but in a modified way

There is no query string on your example source URL to "keep"? Note that the above redirect overwrites any query string that might be present on the source URL. Include the `QSA` on the second `RewriteRule` if you want to "append" the query string from the request.

---

**UPDATE:**

> the first "folder" can vary (e.g. `http://guides.freshstoreinstant.com/fresh-store-builder/...`)

If there is a limited subset of folders then it will probably be better to explicitly name each one, in order to avoid potential conflicts with other URLs on your site. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(fresh-store-(?:instant|builder))/([^/]*)-([^/]*)$ $1/$2+$3 [N]
RewriteRule ^fresh-store-(?:instant|builder)/([^/]+)$ https://guides.freshlabs.group/search?query=$1 [R=302,L]
```

If you make the initial directory entirely variable (such as below) then I can imagine this conflicting with existing URLs:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([^/]*)-([^/]*)$ $1/$2+$3 [N]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([^/]+)$ https://guides.freshlabs.group/search?query=$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer I used. I specified the "folder" explicitly, as suggested in your edit, as there are 7 folders

Works perfectly 

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using apache's rewrite module it does not support such search&replace actions. It only rewrites. If you really cannot live with the unaltered string which you probably could still split in your processing logic, then you have these options:

either introduce another rewriting layer, based on some scripting engine which accepts the unaltered string, converts it by means of normal string operations and output redirection headers

or you may be able to do something with apache's substitute module, but youneed to install and load that and it's usage is not exactly easy (did that, grumbled a lot...)

or use a strange looking but working workaround:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^guides\.freshstoreinstant\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?fresh-store-instant/([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)/?$ https://guides.freshlabs.group/search?query=$1+$2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7+$8+$9 [R=301,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^guides\.freshstoreinstant\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?fresh-store-instant/([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)/?$ https://guides.freshlabs.group/search?query=$1+$2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7+$8 [R=301,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^guides\.freshstoreinstant\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?fresh-store-instant/([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)/?$ https://guides.freshlabs.group/search?query=$1+$2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7 [R=301,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^guides\.freshstoreinstant\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?fresh-store-instant/([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)/?$ https://guides.freshlabs.group/search?query=$1+$2+$3+$4+$5+$6 [R=301,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^guides\.freshstoreinstant\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?fresh-store-instant/([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)/?$ https://guides.freshlabs.group/search?query=$1+$2+$3+$4+$5 [R=301,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^guides\.freshstoreinstant\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?fresh-store-instant/([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)/?$ https://guides.freshlabs.group/search?query=$1+$2+$3+$4 [R=301,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^guides\.freshstoreinstant\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?fresh-store-instant/([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)/?$ https://guides.freshlabs.group/search?query=$1+$2+$3 [R=301,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^guides\.freshstoreinstant\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?fresh-store-instant/([^/-]*)-([^/-]*)/?$ https://guides.freshlabs.group/search?query=$1+$2 [R=301,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^guides\.freshstoreinstant\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?fresh-store-instant/([^/-]*)/?$ https://guides.freshlabs.group/search?query=$1 [R=301,QSA]
```

This rule set will work likewise in the http servers host configuration *or* in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style file).

---

UPDATE:

I realized that your example string to be converted contains more than 9 tokens which is the more or less hard coded limit of back references supported by an apache http server. You could change that if you can recompile the sources, in that case the above solution is fine and can be extended up to a number of tokens you feel safe with.

If that is not an option (as typical), you need to try something like this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^guides\.freshstoreinstant\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)query=(.+)&|$
RewriteRule ^/?fresh-store-instant/?$ https://guides.freshlabs.group/search [R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^guides\.freshstoreinstant\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)query=(.+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?fresh-store-instant/([^/-]*)[-]?(.*)/?$ /fresh-store-instant/$2?query=%2+$1 [N,QSD]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^guides\.freshstoreinstant\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)query=
RewriteRule ^/?fresh-store-instant/([^/-]*)/?$ https://guides.freshlabs.group/search?query=$1 [R=301,QSD]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^guides\.freshstoreinstant\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)query=
RewriteRule ^/?fresh-store-instant/([^/-]*)[-](.*)/?$ /fresh-store-instant/$2?query=$1 [N,QSD]
```

Note: I did not test this, just wrote it down, so there might be some smaller glitch in there. It should work though. It implements a multiple rewriting strategy: it rewrites each token in a separate go, "storing" that token in a preliminary query argument. One by one the tokens are assembled until the final external redirection is performed because no more tokens to be converted are present in the request.

---

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Sorry, there was an issue in my first attempt, I added an UPDATE to the answer which takes that into account. Hope this points you into the right direction.

Comment: Thank you arkascha, I tried it but it didn't work.. and I don't fancy adding apache's substitute module, like you say it seems difficult!

Would a combination of .htaccess and PHP work? Something like:

1) Use .htaccess to rewrite all URL requests to index.php
2) Extract the query string in PHP, replace the characters
3) Redirect to the new URL using PHP

Comment: Sure, that is the first option I pointed out, and it certainly is easy to implement. It is also slow, though.

Comment: Would you mind to explain what you actually mean by "but it didn't work."? Surely this can be brought to work, but such thing needs a bit of tuning, typically.

Comment: Using the code in your update, I get a 404 error on any URL (e.g. http://guides.freshstoreinstant.com/fresh-store-instant/how-to-find)

Comment: Note that the original code works, but there are URLs with more than 9 tokens, and the first "folder" can vary (e.g. http://guides.freshstoreinstant.com/fresh-store-builder/how-do-i-upgrade-fresh-store-builder-to-the-latest-version)

Comment: That the first "folder" is dynamic is another story, you did not mention that is your question, but that can be adapted. Sure, the first approach is limited to 9 tokens, that is why I made the attempt with the second approach. It is slower, but more elegant in the end. I really would like to see this work. Let's see if I can invest a bit more time...

Comment: OK, sorry, tool a while. Turned out that online testers for ".htaccess" style files or rewriting rules are to naive for such non-trivial rule set :-(  So I had to test it with one of my systems. I made some more modifications to the second option and now it works for me and redirects adding a query string with the tokens separated by `+` signs.

Comment: You can do this using mod_rewrite, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54171642/369434).

Comment: Thank you for your input and suggestions @arkascha, it helped me get this working